# Authentication without Passport

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I'm using active directory to authenticate users, so I thought I didn't need to use Passport and that all I would need to do is after the password checks out is to create a global(?) boolean with res.locals to indicate that the user has been authenticated.

I've tried something like this in a controller function:

```
ad.authenticate(username,password, function(err,auth) {

    //some of the things I tried unsuccessfully -- should be true after logged in
    res.locals.auth = auth
    app.locals.auth = auth //app not defined 

})
```

However, I've discovered that when I call a later function checking if the user is logged in as part of middleware for a diff route, res.locals.auth and app.locals.auth are either false or undefined.  I've tried setting both vars in my server.js file at the beg with the code below but that didn't work either...

```
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
  app.locals.auth = false;
  res.locals.auth = false;
  next();
});
```

So my question is, what var/where should I be saving the authenticated status?  Or should I just use passport instead because there's some security concern that I was unaware of?  What is the point of the isMemberOf in passport setup example?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-activedirectory

All I want to do is just check user credentials and basically recreate req.isAuthenticated in Passport because I couldn't figure out how to use it because of the isMemberOf.

Comment: Are you looking to remember the login state _after_ the request? FWIW `res.locals` will not create a global anything, these are temporary variables that exist for the lifespan of the current request.

Comment: @James If I understand this correctly, yes.  So I was reading up on res.locals and it didn't seem to be the soln for that reason, but it kept coming up in examples, and I don't think app.locals is the soln either because it's global/everybody sees it?  Additionally, when I refer to req.locals and app.locals in the next func to check if they're logged in, it kept returning as undefined as well, so I don't know where else to store the state...

Comment: Cookie-session is the key .

Answer (score 2):

Usually the server sends back a token containing some useful data (user or session id, expiration date) either by cookies or by JWT (json web token).

Then a client puts the token into every request to the server . The server validates expiration date and handles requests.

Cookies will be put into a request by the  browser automatically. JWT should be put into a request by your client code.

Comment: JWT is not the secure way , it does not prevent impersonation . yiu should rely on the session and cookies touching with a sort of database.